# React Native: pass responsejson to others screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to bring the response data from the *UserLoginFunction* function in the **LoginActivity** class into the **ProfileActivity** class and then send it to **routes.js**. But there is an error message as follows:

[image]

```
import Routes from './routes';

class LoginActivity extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { dataSource: [] }
    }

    UserLoginFunction = () =>{

        fetch('https://example/login.php', { 
            ....
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                dataSource: responseJson
            });
            this.props.navigation.push('Second', {ds: this.state.dataSource});
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            ...
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View ...
                ...
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.UserLoginFunction} style={styles.button}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>     
            </View>
        );
    }
}


class ProfileActivity extends Component {
    render(){
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        return(
            this.props.navigation.push('Routes', {dataSource: this.props.navigation});
        );
    }
}


export default MainProject = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator( {
    First: { screen: LoginActivity, },
    Second: { screen: ProfileActivity, }
}));
```

Help me please, thank you

Comment: You can't just use state of one class into another because essentially each class is a separate object behind the scenes. You can manage states though by using Flux architecture... try learning about redux and flux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use state to sotre your response that's come from first screen so u pass it well

but in second screen u should do it like this

```
class ProfileActivity extends Component {
  constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
        response: this.props.navigation.getParam('ds')
     }
 }

  render(){
          const { response } = this.state;
          return(
              this.props.navigation.push('Routes', {dataSource: response})
          );
      }
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.
after I fix it, it turns out the following error message appears: 
   98 | constructor(props){
   99 |    super(props);
> 100 |    this.state:{
      |              ^
  101 |       response: this.props.navigation.getParam('ds')
  102 |    }

Comment: There was a typo on this.state: {..., I fixed it to this.state = {... and the wrong message didn't appear, but the next screen (rutes.js) only appeared as a white screen, why

Comment: if the line: **this.props.navigation.push ('Routes', {dataSource: response})** I replace with:**<Routes />** then the next screen runs as it should, but I cannot utilize the dataSource sent from the *UserLoginFunction* function

Comment: can u share ur navigation structure file? u must in the **route** screen get the params like this in the state ```dataSource:this.props.navigation.getParam('dataSource')```

Comment: const Tabs = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator({
 Home: Home,
  About: About,
  Contact: Contact
 },
 {
  tabBarOptions: { ... }
 }
);
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
 { Home:{  screen: Tabs } },
 {
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
 }
);
const MenuImage = ({navigation}) => {
 ....
}
const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
 {
  DrawerNavigator:{ screen: DrawerNavigator }
 },
 {
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
   ...
  })
 }
);
const App = createAppContainer(StackNavigator);
export default App;
 `